# Disabling eventListener on doctrine onFlush while loading fixtures

Tags: doctrine, event-listener, fixtures

I have to persist new entities when app users make modifications on a bunch of existing entities (traceability issue). I created an EventListener on Doctrine `onFlush` event. The problem is: This is not supposed to happen on fixtures loading.
I did this to prevent fixtures from triggering the listener but I wonder if it is a good solution:

In my `services.yaml`:

```yaml
App\DataFixtures\:
    class: App\DataFixtures\LoadFixtures
    tags: [name: doctrine.fixture.orm]
    arguments:
        - '@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager.event_manager'
```

In my `App\DataFixtures\LoadFixtures`:

```php
public function __construct(EventManager $eventManager)
{
    $this->eventManager = $eventManager;
}

public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
{
   $historizationManager = null;

   foreach ($this->eventManager->getListeners() as $event =>$listeners){
       foreach ($listeners as $key => $listener){
           if($listener instanceof HistorizationManager){
               $historizationManager = $listener;
           }
       }
   }

   if($historizationManager){
       $this->eventManager->removeEventListener(array('onFlush'),$onFlushHistoryListener);
   }

   // doing some work
}
```

This is the simplest solution I've come with, please let me know if there is something wrong with that.

Answer (score -2):

If this is still an issue, you could try the following:

- add an `enabled` flag to the EventSubscriber class, default `true`
- use autowiring to make that subscriber available in your fixture loader
- set the flag to `false` before loading the first fixture
- finally, check for that flag before handling the event

But if you've found a better way, I'd be happy to hear from you

To clarify about how to set the flag to `false`: you are usually running your tests in the `test` environment. By using a configuration file like `config_test.yaml`, you can override the default service configuration like:

```
services:
  App\EventSubscribers\YourSubscriber:
    calls:
      - ['setEnabled', [false]]
```

Comment: How would you set the flag to false before loading the first fixture?

Comment: What do you mean by "how"? Just write that down in your class